How to fade in image clip on a background image with MoviePy 2?
I'm using Moviepy2 to render a video based on images. There is one image that should be the background image the whole video. Multiple images should be faded in, showed for a few seconds and faded out again sequentially.
My code generates the video but the foreground_clip is not faded in and out. During the fading I only see a black box.
def create_video(background_image_path, foreground_images_folder, output_video_path):
    # Load and resize the background image
    background_clip = ImageClip(background_image_path)
    print(background_clip)
    print(background_clip.size)
    background_clip = background_clip.resized(VIDEO_RESOLUTION).with_duration(IMAGE_DISPLAY_DURATION)

    # List all images in the foreground images folder
    foreground_images = [os.path.join(foreground_images_folder, img) for img in os.listdir(foreground_images_folder) if img.endswith(('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'))]

    # Create video clips for each foreground image
    clips = []
    for img_path in foreground_images:
        print(f"Processing image: {img_path}")
        foreground_clip = ImageClip(img_path).resized(0.8).with_duration(IMAGE_DISPLAY_DURATION)
        foreground_clip = foreground_clip.with_position('center').with_effects([vfx.CrossFadeIn(1)]).with_effects([vfx.CrossFadeOut(1)])
        composite_clip = CompositeVideoClip([background_clip, foreground_clip])
        clips.append(composite_clip)
        #clips.append(foreground_clip)

    # Concatenate all clips
    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")

    # Write the final video to a file
    final_clip.write_videofile(output_video_path, fps=24)

